# How to exit an app without using action bar and without any physical button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, homescreen, debug-mode

I have an android 4.0 device and it will automatically open an built in application every time when start up. The built in application is written by the company producing this product. I want to write some program for it but since I cannot bypass the application when startup, I cannot go to the setting page and enable debug mode for accessing the file inside. The action bar is disappeared when the built in application is opened. This android device has no any physical button at all except for power on/off button. Does anyone has any idea about how to  bypass the application and go to home screen or access this device in another way?

I have another similar android device but the debug mode for this one is enabled so that I can find the startup default application and delete it (and then I can go back to home screen). However, the device that I am having problem with has disabled debug mode by default. So, I have no idea how to access the device and see the file inside. I cannot do anything at the moment because I cannot even go to the setting page or click any physical button to go startup safe mode or something.

Comment: You can code something like **Shake and close** Do programming of Shake devide and finish activity on shake. :D

Comment: I think this is OS issue. we canot write code for this. please root your phone or do factory reset.